# How to paginate in MongoDB with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents, each having a groupID. I am able to retrieve only one document from each group, but I'm not sure how to do the effective pagination.
Example:

```
{
     unitquantity: "2"
     itemcode: "842852100008"
     name: "Atlas Black"
     price: "39990"
     size: "s"
     groupid: "40bf6073-a1d3-4ffa-9ced-dd2f5fcd1b5e",
},
{
     unitquantity: "2"
     itemcode: "842852100382"
     name: "Atlas Black"
     price: "39990"
     size: "m"
     groupid: "40bf6073-a1d3-4ffa-9ced-dd2f5fcd1b5e",
},
{
     unitquantity: "2"
     itemcode: "842852100746"
     name: "Atlas Black"
     price: "39990"
     size: "xl"
     groupid: "40bf6073-a1d3-4ffa-9ced-dd2f5fcd1b5e",
},
```

These 3 items have a same groupid but they differ on size. I only need to retrieve one from the group, doesn't matter the difference (in this instance it would be size).

I am able to do that with:

```
var query = {[`category.${type}`]: `${type}`}
```

```
var query = {[`category.${type}`]: `${type}`}
db.collection('products').aggregate([
     { $match: query },
     {
          $group: {
               _id: "$groupid",
               images: { $last: "$images" },
               description: { $last: "$description" },
               barcode: { $last: "$barcode" },
               category: { $last: "$category" },
               subcategory: { $last: "$subcategory" }, 
               id: { $last: "$_id" }
          }
     },
     { $sort: {'_id': -1} },
     { $limit: 30 }
]).toArray().then(result=>{
     lastKey = result[result.length - 1].id
     groupId = result[result.length - 1].groupid
})
```

I store the last groupId into the variable. When I press the Load button I want next 30 to appear. Here is my load code which is basically exactly the same except the query for $match uses the document's _id:

```
var query = {[`category.${type}`]: `${type}`, 'groupid': { $ne: `${groupId}`}, '_id': {$gt: lastKey}}
```

```
db.collection('products').aggregate([
     { $match: query },
     {
          $group: {
               _id: "$groupid",
               groupid: { $last: "$groupid" },
               images: { $last: "$images" },
               description: { $last: "$description" },
               barcode: { $last: "$barcode" },
               category: { $last: "$category" },
               subcategory: { $last: "$subcategory" }, 
               id: { $last: "$_id" }
          }
     },
     { $sort: {'_id': -1} },
     { $limit: 30 },
]).toArray().then(result => {
    lastKey = result[result.length - 1].id
    groupId = result[result.length - 1]._id
})
```

However I get many that repeat themselves. 
I saw similar issues other had with $group and $sort and some needed to use $sort before $group and after as well, but it doesn't work for me. I don't really know how to sort them based on document _id correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $skip with the page count. you have to manage page count state in 
  client

```
 db.collection('products').aggregate([
  { $match: query },
  {
      $group: {
           _id: "$groupid",
           groupid: { $last: "$groupid" },
           images: { $last: "$images" },
           description: { $last: "$description" },
           barcode: { $last: "$barcode" },
           category: { $last: "$category" },
           subcategory: { $last: "$subcategory" }, 
           id: { $last: "$_id" }
      }
 },
  { $sort: {'_id': -1} },
  { $skip: 30 * page },
  { $limit: 30 },
]).toArray().then(result => {

 lastKey = result[result.length - 1].id
 groupId = result[result.length - 1]._id

})
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. It skips over a lot of items.